# How to PM2 start more than one processes artisan laravel in one directory?

Tags: laravel, background-process, pm2

i'm using pm2 for using background process, i just have some problems that my system needs 2 background processes but in different artisan command, so i'm using this below step:

```
# install
npm install -g pm2

# in project dir with your CI or dev setup tool 
# --name gives task a name so that you can later manage it
# -- delimits arguments that get passed to the script
pm2 start artisan --interpreter php --name queue-worker -- queue:work --daemon
pm2 start artisan --interpreter php --name schedule-worker -- schedule:work --daemon
```

but when doing that step, my first (queue-worker) process got replaced to a second command (schedule-worker). can you guys give me acommand pm2 that can use more than one processes background in one directory?

Answer (score 0):

a work around would be creating another user on the system you are running your processes on (beside admin), and starting a new pm2 process there, that may work for you.

Although, I do believe that this is not the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

try to start them via a config file

```
{
    "apps": [
        {
        "name": "queue-worker",
        "script": "artisan",
        "args": ["queue:work"],
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": true,
        "max_restarts": 2,
        "interpreter" : "php",
        "watch": true,
        "error_file": "log/err.log",
        "out_file": "log/out.log",
        "log_file": "log/combined.log",
        "time": true
    },
        {
        "name": "schedule-worker",
        "script": "artisan",
        "args": ["schedule:work"],
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": true,
        "max_restarts": 2,
        "interpreter" : "php",
        "watch": true,
        "error_file": "log/err.log",
        "out_file": "log/out.log",
        "log_file": "log/combined.log",
        "time": true
    }
]
}
```

pm2 start config_file_name.json